# Global Menu in Ubuntu 12.04 is not working untill after using a program once?

Tags: menu

I am useing Ubuntu 12.04 and the Global menu is not working untill after I have used any program or the dashboard at least once. I was wondering if any one knew anything about this and if there was a way to fix it. However the Menu seems to work fine after useing a program or the dash but it is just anoying to be forced to open something you dont need to in order to do something else. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by not working? For example, what happens exactly when you open Firefox? Is there no Firefox menu in the top panel?